# will MATLAB run on Ubuntu Mobile?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, matlab

If Ubuntu Mobile allows you to run a desktop operating system on a mobile device, does that mean it is possible to install and run applications such as Matlab?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: MATLAB is a closed-source, commercial application, so cannot just be rebuilt for a new architecture, rather the vendor has to provide a new build. Whether Mathworks intends to support ARM (the CPU architecture for Ubuntu mobile, as opposed to the i386 and AMD64 desktop architectures) you will have to ask them - mobile devices don't seem an obvious match for the sort of heavy work MATLAB is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there will be an ARM build of MATLAB, then this will be possible, but I highly doubt that Mathworks will make such release.